# Tracking Events with Google Universal Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have added this code in my blog for click tracking:

```
<script>
var trackOutboundLink = function (url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
      'hitCallback': function () {
         document.location = url;
      }
   });
}
</script>

<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">Check out example.com</a>
```

But Google Analytics is not showing any click. Maybe code is not working properly.

Will you please suggest me the issue with the code?

Blog Url : http://beebom.com/

Comment: Could it possibly be the odd looking open quotation marks in onclick?

Comment: @khalid13 I changed the code like you suggested. How much time will it take to reflect on google analytics?

Comment: I called the function in the console and the Google Debugger showed that the event was sent. So I don't think there is anything wrong with the function (however it seems the function is nowhere called on the arstechnica homepage).

Comment: @EikePierstorff I have added click event on this page [link](http://thetecnica.com/2014/04/the-story-of-a-web-designers-life-in-15-gifs) but getting unusual results . Please check the screenshot.[link](http://imgur.com/VbaIvnI)

Answer (score 0):

In your post here and on your example page, you used wrong quotation marks resulting in an error:

```
SyntaxError: illegal character
```

Change

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick=”trackOutboundLink(‘http://www.example.com’); return false;">Check out example.com</a>
```

to

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">Check out example.com</a>
```

Don't forget to make the changes on all links on your website.